# ASP.net / c# SQL code submit via textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm relativity new to asp.net / c#. I've written a couple of apps, so i can interpret the language but I'm not fluent.

Basically each year we have students arrive into the college and i want to be able to have a textbox where i can drop the SQL code into and it automatically updates the database. Ofcourse this page will be secured.

But something like this.

```
(,'11JB0666@gmail.org', '12', 'Joe', 'Bloggs', 'Joseph Bloggs', '11JB0666')
```

So that would be the bit of code of the VALUES in the sql script.

Would this be possible?

I did think i could use something like this...

```
SqlConnection conn = new
 SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExtensionActivitesConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" Insert into dbo.Names (Email,Year,FirstName,LastName,Name,Username) VALUES (@SQL)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SQL", SqlTextBox.Text);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

Any help or suggestions would be great thanks.

Comment: I can't advise enough against allowing you to submit SQL directly -- **especially** to a production or integral system database. You could accomplish the same effect just using a form and fully parameterized sql. I do fully understand your position and goal and although it seems like a quick utility it could really bite you down the road. It is worth the extra effort just to do it safely and there are plenty of simple form->database asp.net ado.net examples around that help you accomplish that.

Answer (score 8):

This is a **terrible** and potentially dangerous approach. I suggest that you create a form which collects the information you need, with individual, properly labeled fields.

Since you're only collecting a small amount of data, the form should be very simple. It should include both client-side and server-side validation before you insert the data into your DB.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work with a parameterized query like you're doing -- the single quotes will be escaped and the SQL sent to the server will not be valid. That pattern is used to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You would be better off creating a complete form with all the fields you want and passing the individual fields to your SQL statement. Create a separate TextBox for each field you want to insert into your `Names` table. In my example below, I have named  them emailTextBox, yearTextBox, firstnameTextBox, lastnameTextBox, nameTextBox, and usernameTextBox.

Also, although I am providing a very basic example, you should probably *validate* each field before you actually send the data to the database. You should validate to ensure required fields have values as well as for format -- email for example has a very specific format, and year should probably be a number. For more information on validation, see the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542.aspx

Example:

```
var qry = "Insert into dbo.Names (Email,Year,FirstName,LastName,Name,Username) " + 
          "VALUES (@email, @year, @firstname, @lastname, @name, @username)";    
var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", yearTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstnameTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastnameTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: +1 for following up on James' answer and giving him an example.

Comment: Steve, in case it isn't immediately clear to you, Randolpho's approach uses a different textbox for each input value.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Thanks for pointing that out; I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it is clear that the values are pretty much defined and there is nothing dynamic, so you should provide a proper form to enter the data.

This approach is vary dangerous and is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I totally understand what everyone is saying. However in this instance I don't think a form is the correct approach. We would only run this once a year and we would be inserting 120 students names into the database. I would like this task performed by a non admin so I don't really want them going into the SQL database and inserting them that way. Jut thought there might be a way. I know you can do it in the phpmyadmin web page ?

Comment: I think you are worried about the amount of work involved in making a web form, but believe me it should not take more than a day to develop the form including all the validation.

Comment: It's not the work involved in the form its time to input 120 names

Comment: What about using a CSV file to upload ? Does anyone know how to do this?